# Create a Sortable html table in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, html-table

Using Google Scripts I have an HTML table and would like to make the columns sortable.

Is there a way to do this with either the sortable or tablesorter jQuery plugin as I don't see how to call these without hosting them on my own public server and I see no way of including them in a js folder on Google Scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in Google Scripts, you have the Google Visualization API available to you via the [Default Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/defaultservices). This includes the [TableChartBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_tablechartbuilder), which can yield the results you're asking about.

Here's [an example](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxk5xiLQ0Dvx9ZUE_yoOG_zL6QTK1v8Zlg3hMgn3B_rXS_NMMhF/exec), based on the charting examples from [Visualize Your Data: Charts in Google Apps Script!](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.ca/2011/09/visualize-your-data-charts-in-google.html), which also explains how to publish the chart.

```
function doGet() {    
  // Populate the DataTable.  We'll have the data labels in   
  // the first column, "Release", and then add two data columns,  
  // for "Income" and "Expenses"  
  var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable()      
        .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Release")      
        .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Income")      
        .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Expenses")      
        .addRow(["1.0", 60, 55])      
        .addRow(["10.2", 50, 60])      
        .addRow(["2.10", 100, 50])
        .addRow(["12.0.1", 70, 60])      
        .addRow(["2.0.0.142", 30, 50])
        .addRow(["2.0.0.1_2", 114, 75])
        .build();

  // Build the chart. 
  var chart = Charts.newTableChart()
      .setDataTable(dataTable)  
      .build();

  // Add our chart to the UI and return it so that we can publish  
  // this UI as a service and access it via a URL.  
  var ui = UiApp.createApplication();  
  ui.add(chart);  
  return ui;
}
```